# How to compare nullable decimal in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to compare nullable decimal values ​​from the database in entity framework LINQ.

I tried these approaches:

```
return Db.Products.Any(x =>
        (x.WholeSalePriceVATOut== null && product.WholeSalePriceVATOut== null) ?
        true : (x.WholeSalePriceVATOut== null || product.WholeSalePriceVATOut== null) ?
        false : (Decimal.Compare((decimal)x.WholeSalePriceVATOut, (decimal)product.WholeSalePriceVATOut) == 0) ? true : false)
```

And

```
return Db.Products.Any(x =>
    ((x.WholeSalePriceVATOut.HasValue) ? (decimal?)Math.Round((decimal)x.WholeSalePriceVATOut, 3) : null) == ((product.WholeSalePriceVATOut.HasValue) ? (decimal?)Math.Round((decimal)product.WholeSalePriceVATOut, 3) : null))
```

And

```
return Db.Products.Any(x =>
Decimal.Compare((x.WholeSalePriceVATOut == null) ? -1 : (decimal)x.WholeSalePriceVATOut, (product.WholeSalePriceVATOut == null) ? -1 : (decimal)product.WholeSalePriceVATOut) == 0) ? true : false)
```

All of these examples throw:

> Nullable object must have a value

Is there some elegant way to compare nullable decimal?

Comment: Did you try just  `Where(x => x.WholeSalePriceVATOut == product.WholeSalePriceVATOut)`?

Comment: It's worth noting that if you look at nullable equality using SQL-colored glasses, then two NULL-valued things are never equal.  For example, this: `declare @x int = null;
declare @y int = null;
select case when @x=@y then 'AreEqual' else 'NotEqual' end` results in `NotEqual`.  This is very different from C#-land, where tests like `if (x==null)` are routine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Nullable.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.equals). The following should be sufficient:

```
return Db.Products.Any(p => 
          Nullable.Equals(p.WholeSalePriceVATOut, product.WholeSalePriceVATOut));
```

When EF converts that into SQL, the relevant part of the SQL will be something like:

```sql
WHERE (`Product`.`WholeSalePriceVATOut` = @p__0) OR 
      ((`Product`.`WholeSalePriceVATOut` IS  NULL) AND (@p__0 IS  NULL))))
```

Comment: This works.  I'll add Linq to Entities also supports using the null coalescing operator, so you can use `??` if you want some specific default value for null.

Comment: This works, but problem is how to compare it to some decimal accuracy. What I ended up doing is when creating Product class I round the decimal value if not null to same digits as in database, so after that this comparison works. Thank you!

Comment: @MichalFiala You may use `Nullable.Compare<decimal>()`.